# Ionic 2: Dismiss loading animation when iframe is ready

Tags: html, angular, iframe, typescript, ionic-framework

I have to include a external webpage in my app, so I use an iframe for this.
Now I want to show an loading animation, while the iframe is loading. That works fine, but I don't know, how to dismiss the animation, when the iframe is ready.
I can't edit the code of the page in the iframe.

That's my code on the TypeScript-File:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.presentLoading();
}

presentLoading() {
    let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        content: 'Please wait...'
    });

    loading.present();
}
```

and the HTML file

```
<ion-content>
    <iframe name="chatFrame" src="http://..."></iframe>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: I believe this question may have been answer here: [Checking Load State on an Iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17158932/how-to-detect-when-an-iframe-has-already-been-loaded/36155560#36155560)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach onLoad iframe method to a function that will dismiss your loading animation.

```
<ion-content>
    <iframe name="chatFrame" src="http://..." (load)="dismissLoading()"></iframe>
</ion-content>
```

And in your component class :

```
loading;

ngOnInit() {
    this.presentLoading();
}

presentLoading() {
    this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
       content: 'Please wait...'
    });

    loading.present();
}

dismissLoading(){
    this.loading.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but i get "this.loading.dismiss() is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is wrong, I modify it and it can run perfectly：

```
dismissLoading(){
   //this.loading.dismiss();
     this.loadingCtrl.dismiss();
}
```