# How switch to iFrame with Cypress

Tags: cypress

I use Cypress to automate logging in to a web application, protected by an iFrame.

In my Selenium I can use a command to switch to iFrame:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*@id='app']/iframe")));
```

After that I can access iFrame elements as well.

But with Cypress, I don't know the method to switch to frame?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I enter data into a form input in an iframe using cypress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47325258/how-do-i-enter-data-into-a-form-input-in-an-iframe-using-cypress?rq=1)

Comment: @JoshuaWade: thank you for your comment, I have found solution to resolve it.
cy.get('iframe').then(function ($element) {
  const $body = $element.contents().find('body')
  const cyElement = cy.wrap($body) 
   cyElement.find('[class=xxx]').click({force:true})
I hope this can help somebody save your time.

Answer (score 0):

In Cypress, you need to install a package called `cypress-iframe` in order to work on iFrame elements.

**Run this command in your terminal to install:**

```
npm install -D cypress-iframe
```

Import `cypress-iframe` package to your file:

```
import 'cypress-iframe';
```

To load an iFrame, use:

```
cy.frameLoaded("#id-of-an-iframe");
```

To find element inside iFrame, start with:

```
cy.iframe()
```

Here is the code example on how to use iFrame elements in Cypress:

```
/// <reference types="Cypress" />
/// <reference types="cypress-iframe" />
import 'cypress-iframe';

describe("Test Suite", () => {
    it("Test Case", () => {

        cy.visit("https://example.com");

        cy.frameLoaded("#iframe-id"); //Load iFrame

        cy.iframe().find("a[href*='services']").eq(0).click();  //click on link inside iFrame
        cy.iframe().find("h1[class*='service-title']").should("have.length", 2);  //assertion

    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this by writing one method which will go inside the Iframe

```
getIframeBody(){
        return cy.get('object').its('0.contentDocument').its('body').then(cy.wrap)
    }
```

Then use this method to procced further like:

```
this.getIframeBody().xpath("your xpath").click();
```

If you are writing `getIframeBody()` method somewhere else then create an object or extends that class and use super keyword to call `getIframeBody()` method like:

```
super.getIframeBody().xpath("your xpath").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a switch like webdriver io per say, it's more of an access inside the iframe's window content. This [link](https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/using-cypress-faq#How-do-I-get-the-native-DOM-reference-of-an-element-found-using-Cypress) explains it pretty well