# how to click on iframe Submit button using cypress?

Tags: javascript, html, testing, automation, cypress

UI: [IFrame UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqUhA.png)

Code: [HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHXMR.png)

I am expecting solution. Please help me out.

Code Which I tried:

```
cy.get('cpwa__frame').its('0.contentDocument.body').then(cy.wrap).find('#btn btn-primary').should ('have', 'Submit').click();
```

Another I tried:

```
cy.get('cpwa__frame').its('0.contentDocument.body').find('.btn btn-primary').click();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cypress 12.8.1 not working with Stripe Elements iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75882883/cypress-12-8-1-not-working-with-stripe-elements-iframe)