# Cypress Iframe cannot find 0.contentDocument

Tags: iframe, cypress

I am trying to run some tests on our application that requires uploading of users. We use usecsv to handle uploaded documents in an iframe on our page. When trying to use multiple different approaches in order to run tests against it, I keep getting in the situation where cypress errors with:

> Timed out retrying after 4000ms: cy.its() errored because the property: `0.contentDocument` does not exist on your subject.

I tried comparing with a different website to see if my commands were correct:

```js
describe("iFrame", () => {
 
    beforeEach(() => {
      cy.visit('https://kitchen.applitools.com/ingredients/iframe');
    });
   
    it('should find a table in the iframe', () => {
      cy.get('iframe[src="/ingredients/table"]')
        .its('0.contentDocument').its('body').then(cy.wrap);
    });
  });`
```

```html
<iframe id="the-kitchen-table" title="The Kitchen - Table" 
  width="800" height="800" 
  src="/ingredients/table">
</iframe>
```

which works as expected.

When running similar against my app:

```js
describe("Sets up benefits, edits them and verifies functionality", () => {
    it("Changes employee start date for gratuity calculations", () => {
      cy.visit("/");

...
      cy.get('iframe[src="https://app.usecsv.com/importer"]')  
        .its('0.contentDocument').its('body').then(cy.wrap);
    });
})
```

```html
<iframe src="https://app.usecsv.com/importer"></iframe>
```

In this case I receive said error. When just trying `cy.get('iframe[src="https://app.usecsv.com/importer"]')` there is no error, so I am assuming it does find the iframe, but not the doc. Tried numerous solutions from other posts, but none of it seems to be working for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

`https://kitchen.applitools.com` uses a static page that just loads HTML. Some iframes run javascript which resets the `contentDocument`.

I suggest in the first instance try [cypress-iframe](https://gitlab.com/kgroat/cypress-iframe)

```js
cy.enter('iframe[src="https://app.usecsv.com/importer"]').then(getBody => {
  getBody().find(...)
  getBody().contains(...)
})
```

If that does not help, try a recursive approach such as given here
[Cypress 12.8.1 not working with Stripe Elements iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75883621/21667729)

Comment: That unfortunately seems to trigger a security issue:

Failed to read a named property 'toString' from 'Location': Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:3500" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Even when adding: chromeWebSecurity: false, to the cypress.config.js file