# how to know when an iframe has finished loading the DOM, but not yet all images?

Tags: javascript

My web page has an iframe, and I change its src when the user clicks on a `showNewPage` button. I need to know when the browser has finished loading the DOM of the iframe, but without waiting for all the images to be downloaded.

```
var myIFrame = document.getElementById("myIframe")
var count = 0;
funcion showNewPage() {
  myIFrame.src = "http://example.com/page_" + count;
  count++;
}
```

This code calls `doSomething()` when the iframe has finished loading the DOM and all images:

```
myIFrame.addEventListener("load", function(event) { doSomething(); });
```

How to ask myIFrame to call `doSomething()` when the iframe has finished loading the DOM, but not yet all the images?

---

ps: There is an event `DOMContentLoaded` instead of `load` which achieves this; but this event is not available for an iframe. It's available only for a document or a window. Doing as follows does not work neither, because `myIFrame.contentWindow` returns null at the very beginning:

```
myIFrame.contentWindow.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { doSomething(); });
```

ps: this other question does not answer my question, as it relies on `onload` event, which waits until all images are downloaded: [How to detect when an iframe has already been loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17158932/how-to-detect-when-an-iframe-has-already-been-loaded)

Comment: Maybe place `DOMContentLoaded`on the iframe itself and make it output some hidden flag that the main window can communicate with?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect when an iframe has already been loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17158932/how-to-detect-when-an-iframe-has-already-been-loaded)

Comment: @A.Meshu, the iframe does not fire the `DOMContentLoaded` event; it only fires the `load` event. This is the issue.

Comment: @ℛɑƒæĿ, the question you mention uses the `onload` event, which is fired when all images finished downloading. I need to know when the DOM is loaded without waiting for all the images to be downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

As you found out, trying to get its `.contentWindow` before the iframe has been initialized will return `null`.

One way around this is to

- initialize your frame with an empty document (`about:blank`),
- get a reference to your iframe's `contentWindow`, this will always be the same object, however events we attach on it will get removed at every new navigation...
- add an `unload` event listener (since it's the closest to the navigation)
- wait just a frame so our `contentWindow` start the navigation
- add your `DOMContentLoaded` and our `unload` event listeners so we can reiterate at next navigation

```
frame.onload = e => {
  const win = frame.contentWindow;
  frame.onload = null;
  win.addEventListener( 'unload', attachEvents );
  YOUR_CALLBACK(); // make it fire even at beginning?

  function attachEvents()  {
    setTimeout( () => {
      win.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', YOUR_CALLBACK );
      win.addEventListener( 'unload', attachEvents ); // do it again at next navigation
    }, 0 );
  };
};
frame.src = "about:blank";
```

[As a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1keyx4nL/) since StackSnippets over-protected iframes don't allow us to access inner frames' content...